# How do I use OAuth2 to authenticate for Google Cloud API in PHP

Tags: php, api, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I am trying to interact with Google Cloud APIs using the https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php packages.

For instance, here I am issuing a request for Billing Accounts:

```
$client = new CloudBillingClient();
$accounts = $client->listBillingAccounts();

foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    print('Billing account: ' . $account->getName() . PHP_EOL);
}
```

This obviously doesn't work as there are no credentials, and throws an error:

```
Google\ApiCore\ValidationException
Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials
```

So how do I authenticate to get the Billing query to work? To be clear, I can use another OAuth2 library to get an access_token, no problems. For example in this Laravel controller:

```
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google as GoogleProvider;

class GoogleAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $provider = new GoogleProvider([
            'clientId'     => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            'redirectUri'  => $redirectUri // will use this same url 'index'
        ]);

        $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl([
            'scope' => [
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
            ]
        ]);

        // This is the first request for authorization
        if (empty($_GET['code']))
        {
            session()->put('oauth2state', $provider->getState());
            return redirect($authUrl);
        }
        // This is the returned request from Google
        else
        {
            $token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
                'code' => $_GET['code']
            ]);

            // I HAVE A TOKEN NOW! I can do a request using Guzzle, like below, and it works fine.
            // But surely Google's package should allow me to do this?!?!?

            $response = Http::get('https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects', [
                'access_token' => $token
            ]);
            return $response;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would like to leverage the power of Google's already-built libraries.

Looking through the Google Auth package for PHP (https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php) I see lots of mention of OAuth, and it seems *possible* to use credentials generated by that library with the Google Cloud packages (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php), like the BillingClient above. But I am struggling with *how*.

**Edit**

Further to this: in jdp's answer below he uses the 'credentials' config key. Note this comment in the source of CloudBillingGapicClient: "In addition, this option can also accept a pre-constructed \Google\Auth\FetchAuthTokenInterface object or \Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper} object". When I look at the OAuth2 class in Google's Auth package I see that it implements FetchAuthTokenInterface. So it seems like it should be usable to pass OAuth credentials. I am just lost as to how.

Comment: From my understanding you created your app credentials in your project. You can get only an access token to your project, you can not access my project. The only way to access my project is to create a service account and I should add this service account in  my project with the wright permission. Otherwise, you can not access my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service account and download the credentials file, then configure [application default credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually). From there clients will be automatically authenticated.

You can also provide the credentials directly when creating a client:

```php
$client = new CloudBillingClient([
    'credentials' => '/path/to/keyfile.json'
]);

$accounts = $client->listBillingAccounts();

foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    print('Billing account: ' . $account->getName() . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However I need to be able to work on many users Google Cloud accounts and this would require each of them to download their keyfile and upload it to my server, right? I wanted a much more user-friendly method of authenticating, thus the OAuth approach. And I can confirm I have it working with my own code.

Comment: what do you mean you want to work on many users? do you want to list the billing accounts of one project? of multiple projects that a user has? or multiple projects with different users?

Comment: My web app has many users. Each one can connect their Google account to my web app through OAuth2 and then be able to interrogate their projects and billing *through my app*. So for each of my apps users they will grant my app permission to access their Google account and I will get an access token from Google and can then request data from Google about that users projects and billing accounts. This is what my custom code is doing above; I would just like to use Google own packages for their APIs to do so.

Comment: I have also added some details to my question above if it helps.